# Set Ember controller property false when changing route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-components

I have a music component playing the favorites songs retrieved from the SoundCloud API inside the Music Page of my website.

```
{{soundcloud-player favorite=currentFavorite sound=currentFavoriteObject position=currentFavoritePosition isPlaying=isPlaying isBuffering=isBuffering}}
```

The problem is once i play a song and i change page ( route ) of the website , the songs keeps playing, to resolve it i need to set  `isPlaying` `false` anytime i change the Music `route` of the page.

I see there are different ways to achieve it but i can not figure it out for my case

Mi tries

From a different controller

```
needs:'player',
desactivateIsplaying: function(){
    var controller = this.get('controllers.player');
    controller.set('isPlaying', false);
}
```

or from a different route

```
desactivateIsPlaying: function(){
    var controller = this.controllerFor('player');
    controller.set('isPlaying', false);
}
```

In any of the two functions i can not set `isPlaying` `false`, i have also seen mentioned the `willTransition` route action, how can i use it? is there any better way do that? If necessary i can make a twiddle ember to reproduce better the scenario

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `willTransition` on your route is a good option.

**music/route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { Route } = Ember;

export default Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition() {
      this.controller.set('isPlaying', false);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Today i will try this out and let you know, which arguments you mean?

Comment: We don't actually need to call `super()` here because `willTransition` is an even rather than an overridable method. /cc @Kitler

Comment: To answer the question though, there's two things happening with `...arguments`. 1) `arguments` are available within every JS function as an array of *all* incoming arguments, 2) the `...` is called the spread operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and allows you to pass all arguments to another method. `this._super(...arguments)` is needed when overriding a builtin Ember method that contains functionality we don't want to lose by overriding.

Comment: @Kitler one of my colleagues pointed out there's a case for calling super on willTransition: if you're mixing in another object that has `willTransition()` defined.